# Unity keeps crashing back into login screen

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, xorg

Every now and then my desktop freezes and after a few seconds i will see the login screen again. My system is only hours old, and did no bigger changes to the UI. There is no real trigger, seems to be random.

I did however install NVIDIA drivers over the "Additional Drivers" Settings. Version 352.63.

[dmesg.txt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14883195/)

[Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14883201/)

Since i'm not able to find the source of this problem, i hope someone here can help me. If you need more logs, or any other infomation, just ask.

Specs: MSI z77-g43 i5-2500k GTX 760 - Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS

Comment: After installing I did follow [my custom list](https://bitbucket.org/daputzy/thingstodoafterinstallingubuntu/overview) on what to do after a fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the NVIDIA drivers and reinstall them in a different way.

**Step 1 : Uninstall the NVIDIA drivers**

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

**Step 2 : Reinstall the NVIDIA drivers**

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

In case the problem still occurs, install the latest official drivers.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Until now no crashes, looks like it worked, thanks!