# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes into login screen

Tags: nvidia, gnome, 18.04, login, crash

Whenever I try to do either of the following:

- open information about a Wi-Fi connection in the WiFi settings
- open Activity Log Manager app
- try to Save As file in VS Code
- try to Add Printer,

all of a sudden, Ubuntu crashes and all I have is the login screen back in front of me.

My specs are:

- Intel i7-7500u GeForce 940MX
- GNOME on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

These crashes aren't random, they only happen whenever I trigger one of the aforementioned tasks. I've re-installed Ubuntu like more than 3 times, but the same problem persists.

*I'm new to linux, so I don't know that much technical terms of ubuntu.*

***PS*** - I've tried to reinstall *NVidia driver* as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729793/unity-keeps-crashing-back-into-login-screen), but the problem still persists.

***PPS*** - If I try to login using *Ubuntu Wayland*, opening the Settings app only crashes the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by resetting the settings I tweaked in the GNOME Tweaks Tool and then rebooting. I guess the problem was with the shell theme I was using.